# Random error occurs every so often: attempt to compare nil with number Corona SDK

Tags: android, ios, lua, sdk, coronasdk

Every so often my app will throw the following error:

gamePlay.lua:121: attempt to compare nil with number

The function moves an object from the right of the screen to the left. When it goes 50 pixels offscreen then the object should remove. Here is my code for the method:

```
function moveObject(self,event)

        if (self.x)<-50 then --this is line 121
            --remove object
            Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", event.self)
            display.remove(event.target)

        else
            self.x = self.x-self.speed --move object left at value speed
        end
    end
```

The error pops up when this method is called and it goes to the restart screen:

------when ball hits another object go to restart scene------------

```
    local function onCollision( self,event )

        if(event.object2.name == "bonus")then--if we hit a bonus ball
            event.object2:removeSelf()

            --set score
            local currentScore =game.returnScore()
            game.setScore(currentScore*2)
            scoreText.text = game.returnScore()

            Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", event.object2)

        else                

            composer.gotoScene("restart")   
            Runtime:removeEventListener("touch", onObjectTouch)    
        end
    end
    ball.collision = onCollision
    Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", ball )
```

Any ideas what could be happening? It is quite rarely that the error occurs, maybe 1 in 15 goes.

Comment: Yes I understand the error but am wondering how to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with your event listeners. I sometimes find with Corona that event listeners still run even after a scene has changed. I'm guessing that the ball is cleaned up (removed) before the event listener is stopped, and that every now and then the listener is still being run before the listener is cleaned up

To fix it, you could try

1. removing the listener first, ball second
2. simply adding a null check before the if check

   > ```
   > if (self ~= null) then
   > if (self.x)<-50 then --this is line 121
   >         --remove object
   >         Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", event.self)
   >         display.remove(event.target)
   > ```

Comment: `null` -> `nil` in Lua.

Comment: I would also write it in the same statement: `if (self ~= nil) and (self.x < -50)`. Lua checks the first condition first and only if it's true it will check the second condition i.e. there is no way that it will check the second condition, self.x, if the first condition, self is nil, is not met..

Comment: I tried implementing that idea but the problem still remains unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved a similar problem by not just checking if "self" is nil, but checking if "self.x" is nil. So...

if self ~= nil and self.x ~= nil and self.x < -50 then

I'm not entirely sure why this works but I'm guessing corona is removing the display object properties and not the object itself.